# Misuses of notation $Y|X$

Tags: probability

In the context of using conditional distributions, it has been mentioned by many here that $Y|X$, where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables defined on the same probability space, is a misleading notation.

In order to clarify the confusion and what its users intend to do with the notation, could you think of 
what $Y|X$ might actually represents in what cases,  how the confusion arises, and what is the correct notation to use instead in those cases?

Does $Y|X=x$ make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: @StefanHansen: what do you think its users intend to represent, and what are correct notations for what they intend to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you throw two dice, let $X$ is the result of the first die and $Y$ be the result of the second die. Then it wouldn't make much sense to ask about the "probability that the result of the second die, given that the result of the first die". It's much more sensible to ask for the "probability that the second die results in $y$, given that the result of the first die is $x$". So if you ask for a probability, then $P(Y=y\mid X = x)$ is the most sensible notation.

However, if you just write $Y\mid X = x$, it still makes sense as a random variable in it's own right. It will be the random variable "The result of the second die, given that the first die was thrown an $x$". So to be *entirely correct*, perhaps it is better to write $(Y\mid X = x) = y$ rather than $Y=y\mid X = x$, but I have never seen anyone actually do this.

Of course, in the end, you might still see someone write $P(Y\mid X)$, and let the $ = y$ and $=x$ be implicit.

Comment: agreed. In my opinion, part of the confusion (which I often experience when _writing_ mathematics), is that P(Y|X) does make sense when Y and X are events.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure if  the random variable "The result of the second die, given that the first die was thrown an x" can be a formal enough definition for $Y|X=x$. If possible, can you formally write the random variable $Y|X=x$ in terms of $Y$ and $X$? I agree $Y|X=x$ isn't any random variable which has the same distribution, and it should be defined in terms of $Y$ and $X$.

Comment: "if you just write $Y\mid X = x$, it still makes sense as a random variable in it's own right." No it does not, as has already been explained on the site (to this OP, if I remember correctly), since the only random variable this notation could allude to would be defined on $\{X=x\}$, not on $\Omega$.

Comment: "the only random variable this notation could allude to would be defined on {X=x}, not on Ω." well said, @Did